# Yii counter query in findall

Tags: php, yii

I have the following query

```
UserLogin::model()
-> with(array(
    'Provider'=> array(
        'select'=>'name'
    )
))
-> findAll(array(
    'select' => 'count(t.id) as count ',
    'group'=>'provider_id',
    'order'=>'provider_id'
));
```

and my view is

```
<?php foreach($providerCounts as $providerCount): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $providerCount['Provider']['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $providerCount['count']; ?></td>             
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is the relation

```
'Provider'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Provider', 'provider_id'),
```

I am getting the error

> Property "UserLogin.counts" is not defined.

The same query in a different model is working.

Now i have two question

- Why is the query not working
- How do i debug such errors in yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need specify public property count

```
class UserLogin extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $count = 0;

    public function rules() {
        // ...
        array('count', 'safe'),
        // ...
    }
}
```

For debug use xdebug for php + ext for FireFox for debugging php

Also use `yii-debug-toolbar` (search in yii ext site)

Comment: why should i add a public property

Comment: because, this column is not exist in the table

Comment: but the same thing works in another table without mentioning this

Comment: @WebDeveloper, Carefully inspect - perhaps it uses replacement or there is a column with the same name

Answer (score 1):

You need to have UserLogin.count property so Yii can assign returned DB value to model when you use `as` in your AR requests.

Comment: I mean add a 'blaBlaBla' public property in your UserLogic model if you have `count(...) as blaBlaBla` in your request.

Comment: why should i add a publoc property